# how to change database structure correctly when working with Flyway?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

For example I have script `V1__InitScript.sql` with query:

```
create table if not exists users
(
  guid varchar(36) not null primary key,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  description varchar(500)
);
```

I start My app on clear DB and flyway run this script. Now I have emty table with name `users` and 3 colums. I start work and I need add one column, for example `age`. what should i do?

1) I can add this column to table. And after that add this query to `V2__Add_column.sql`. But When I start app flyway try make this V2 script because it not exist in `flyway_schema_history` table.

2) When I want to add a column, I immediately add it with `flyway`. But when I do active development I can often change the data. So I have to run `flyway` for every change?

It seems reasonable to change the structure of the database, and the scripts to collect in a separate file. and when preparing a new release, add all the necessary scripts to `flyway`. But how can I be on my developer machine? Or do I not need to run the `flyway` on my machine, but only on test and production?

and another question - how to build a process correctly, if the work is done with the same base for all developers. Ie the developer has no local database on the computer

Answer (score 0):

For me the most convenient way was to have a development database, which is not populated by Flyway and could be modified manually at anytime, and some database for testing, which is populated by Flyway only and never manually, and is used for any testing purposes (include tests automation). And for sure, Flyway should be used in the production.

This way you are free to modify your database during development and can still have all the advantages of Flyway for your deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You should aim to keep all your environments as identical as possible. Flyway usage is no exception here. Use it everywhere, even in dev.

As you use Spring Boot, make sure Flyway is run automatically when the ApplicationContext is started. This will ensure that the database is automatically migrated both on app and on unit test startup.

To iterate rapidly in dev you can active Flyway's `cleanOnValidationError` mode. This way, every time you modify your latest migration script which you haven't committed yet, its checksum will change, which in turn causes Flyway's validation to fail, which will then with this property trigger a clean of the dev database, which will be immediately followed by migrate to recreate it fully according to the latest version of your scripts.

Comment: `cleanOnValidationError ` this is of course cool. but my dev base is not on my machine. It has a size greater than 100GB (this is a snapshot of the real base). And in it the data that I need to test the functionality that I am writing.